# Why does -z and -n exist in most shells and /bin/test?

Tags: unix, shell, design-choices

The `test` command on Unix-like systems provides two special syntax forms for checking whether a string is empty or not:

```
test -z "$foo" # the length of $foo is zero
test -n "$foo" # the length of $foo is nonzero
```

These forms are actually redundant, and equivalent to the following:

```
test "$foo" = ""
test "$foo" != ""
```

Why are there two different forms? Is there a historical reason or justification for this design decision?

---

Background, as far as I know it. Bash descends from an older shell Almquist shell. The Almquist shell didn't internalize expressions. So you wrote them with using a utility called test which just resolved them to a return code,

```
if test "$foo" = ""; then echo "Foo has a length of 0"; fi;
```

That would call the actually utility `/bin/test` and test that first argument `$foo` was equal to third argument ( an empty string).

It also provided another option,

```
if test -z "$foo"; then echo "Foo has a length of 0"; fi;
```

I don't understand why this syntax exists though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118555/discussion-on-question-by-evan-carroll-why-does-z-and-n-exist-in-most-shells-a).

Comment: The `/bin/test` utility exists to this day. The shell (particularly `bash`) builtin with that name (as several others) is just for performance reasons.

Answer (score 23):

Because `$foo` may itself start with a hyphen and look like an option or an operation, which would cause misinterpretation of the command line. Using `-z` or `-n` guarantees that no matter the contents of `$foo`, it will never be interpreted as an option.

The BSD 2.11 man page for `test` says: *The test grammar is inherently ambiguous. In order to assure a degree of consistency, the cases described in the IEEE Std 1003.2 ("POSIX"), section D11.2/4.62.4, standard are evaluated consistently according to the rules specified in the standards document. All other cases are subject to the ambiguity in the command semantics.*

So whatever can be done to simplify writing unambiguous expressions, helps.

Comment: Wow, this sounds like a valid argument. So back when `test` wasn't internalized as a shell command but existed as a stand alone thing, people had to check that the LHS and RHS did not start with `-`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll The simple cases work (3 operands means that the first and the last are values, and the middle one is the comparison operator). However, the BSD 2.11 man page for `test` says *The test grammar is inherently ambiguous.  In order to assure a degree of consistency, the cases described in the IEEE Std 1003.2 ("POSIX"), section D11.2/4.62.4, standard are evaluated consistently according to the rules specified in the standards document.  All other cases are subject to the ambiguity in the command semantics.*  So whatever can be done to simplify writing unambiguous expressions, helps.

Comment: The 'might start with hyphen' argument is the same argument for [any language that allows lexical substitution](https://xkcd.com/327/) of variables into a command-string before parsing that string.  It's one of the hazards of programming in common scripting languages.

Comment: Jup. Sounds like a great reasoning and well fitting the usual *nix world.

Comment: It doesn't make sense though in light of that quote, how is there any ambiguity if you're providing three arguments regardless of whether or not the first argument starts with a dash.

Comment: `$foo` can start with a dash (or be a `!`, which is worse) even in something like `[ "$foo" = blahblah ]`. So if handling that corner case was the main reason for `-n`, you'd expect to also have a similar prefix operator for equality and inequality testing.

Comment: I think the argument count was added by POSIX to provide an unambiguous way of interpreting arguments, whether or not they begin with a `-`. The fact that the operators *do* still start with hyphens is to remain compatible with historical usage, not a requirement of the argument parser.

Comment: (The fact that boolean `-a` and `-o` mess up the argument-count algorithm is used as one rationale for deprecating them.)

Comment: I've often seen the test being written as `[ "x$foo" = "x" ]`. This way there's no problem of leading dash.

Comment: @Ruslan True, but it is an ugly kludge, like not having a unary minus operation in a programming language, and having to write `0-1` instead of `-1`.

Comment: @Raffzahn I wonder what would be, say, the IBM approach. :)

Answer (score 11):

The argument from consistency:

The majority of `test` commands are of the form `-flag value`.

For example,  `test -e foo.bar` - does file foo.bar exist?

`test -n "$VAR"` fits into that model, and is therefore consistent.

---

The first mention of `test` I could find in 'man' pages is to [this link to the PWB (Programmer's Work Bench) shell](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/PWB/) *aka* Mashey shell, it in turn links to [this page](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/bourne/PWB/if.1.html), which describes a version of `test` that has  both forms: `-n str` and `str !- ""`.
Note that `test` and `if` are the same program.

(Curiously, the title of that second page is 'Thompson shell manual')

PWB started on 4th. ed. Unix, and the Mashey shell was derived from Thompson's original `sh`.  Given the focus of PWB, it's probable that this is the first appearance of 'if' and 'test'.

There is also the paper [Using a Command Language as a High-Level Programming Language](https://grosskurth.ca/bib/1976/mashey-command.pdf), written by Mashey, that describes `if`.  In that paper, the `-n` and `-z` forms are not mentioned, only the string-comparison form.

Two things are possible: (1) at the time of the paper, the full if/test syntax existed in PWB, but the paper is not intended to be exhaustive, or (2) the syntax was later expanded, and/or the 'test' command was added.

Either way, I think this shell is the likely first appearance of 'test' in the shell; plausibly so because it was the explicit intent of PWD to be able to facilitate the programmer's tasks.

We have the first; we can still only guess at the 'why'.  But I still think consistency has a lot to do with it, especially if, as appears possible, the string-comparison form existed before the `-z`/`-n` form.

Comment: Both of these are pretty subjective reasons, and it’s not justified by any source that they were indeed real considerations. The ‘argument from naturalness’ is especially silly, since ‘is empty’ and ‘is equal to the empty string’ are pretty much on the same level on the abstraction ladder; neither is more ‘natural’ than the other. In my answer I mentioned some more pertinent objective reasons for this design.

Comment: Subjective - like most UI issues. Early Unix design is replete with decisions made because that's what the designers liked.

Comment: The design of everything is replete with decisions made because that’s what the designers liked – or sometimes did out of necessity, which only later was retroactively justified, with [the (in)famous `/usr` split](http://landley.net/writing/hackermonthly-issue022-pg33.pdf) as just one example. The question then becomes which is which.

Comment: In some situations where an object will contain a collection of things [strings are a special case of this], testing for whether an object is empty generally means something different from testing whether its contents precisely match those of another collection.  If one wants someone to check whether a package has been delivered, would one ask "Is there anything on the porch" or "Does the porch contain precisely the same set of items as an empty porch"?  Even if a language doesn't provide an "is empty", I would "empty" constants used in equality tests as "fake constants", since...

Comment: ...the only situation where an equality test can reliably indicate whether something contains something else is when the first item would otherwise be empty.  Comparison against anything other than empty could yield false positives if the comparison mismatch is a result of something having been removed rather than added.

Comment: I rewrote much of the answer based on locating a paper describing shell programmability.

Comment: V6's if didn't have -z/-n: https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/source/s1/if.c . An interesting quote from the documentation: _The construction if $1x = x tests whether $1, the first argument, was present or absent._ https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/doc/beg/u4#L175

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: This answer is to an extent speculative, and I’m not sure I can find sources for some of the claims I make here. So I cannot say for certain that this is the definitive reason. But I find it pretty plausible.

---

The `test` command actually provides *three* forms of (non-)emptiness checking:

1. `test "$a"`
2. `test -n "$a"` vs `test -z "$a"`
3. `test "$a" != ""` vs `test "$a" = ""`

In contemporary Unix-like systems, they can be reliably distinguished by counting arguments to the `test` command: one argument means the first form was used, two arguments mean it’s the second form, and three arguments mean it’s the third form. This method [is recommended by SUS](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/test.html) and by POSIX (IEEE 1003.1-2017 vol. 3, ch. 4, pp. 3290–3291). Historically though, different algorithms have been used: some implementations of `test` parsed options like any other utility, matching command line arguments against a list of known options, which caused problems if the string to be tested happened to match one of them. The following transcript, for example, [comes from Version 7 Unix](https://www.jdpressman.com/2015/11/27/how-to-emulate-unix-v7-using-SIMH-(2015).html):

```
$ test '' ; echo $?
1
$ test x ; echo $?
0
$ test -r ; echo $?
test: argument expected
255
$ test '' = '' ; echo $?
0
$ test x = '' ; echo $?
1
$ test x = x ; echo $?
0
$ test -r = -r ; echo $?
1
```

Also, not all of these constructs were available on all systems. Some provided `-z`, but not `-n`, and apparently some even provided neither. Furthermore, there were shells in use in which empty string arguments were not passed to the command executed, so that `test "$a" = ""` could run the `test` command with just two or one arguments, and trigger a syntax error. For these reasons, in `configure` scripts generated by GNU Autoconf, [emptiness testing is performed via the command `test "x$var" = x`](http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/doc/howto.html).  (See also [a pretty comprehensive blog post by Vidar Holen on this subject](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=1035).)

Add to that that some shell scripts did not even bother to quote variables: instead of writing `"$a"` each time, they would write `$a`, so an empty variable would have resulted in an empty string argument even if the shell supported those correctly. (This remains a common shell programming blunder to this day.)

The `-z` option may have originated as a workaround for some of these problems:

- Having an explicit operator ensures that tested strings would not be themselves interpreted as testing operators.
- With a buggy shell that doesn’t pass empty arguments correctly, `test -z "$foo"` may result in `test` being called:

  - If `foo` is non-empty, with two arguments: `-z`, and the contents of `foo`; this then returns failure, as expected.
  - If `foo` is empty, with one argument `-z`, which the `test` command may then interpret as either:

    - a check whether an empty list of remaining arguments is empty (which it is), or
    - a check whether the `-z` string is non-empty, which just so happens to have the same truth value as the emptiness of `"$foo"`.

    Either way, the command returns success – as expected.

The `-n` command may have been added to similarly disambiguate the first form from a missing argument when the string to be tested matches a known `test` operator, e.g. `test -n '-t'` vs `test -t`.

Comment: re: *the earliest shells apparently provided only forms (1) and (3)* -- the earliest mention of 'test' that I found was 7th. Ed. Unix, which already has (2) and (3), not sure of how (1) would be interpreted.  Did you find earlier?  I suspected PWB would have 'test' but not according to man pages.

Comment: I inferred this information from what the Autoconf page said (‘[w]hile "-z" is seen often, even "-n" is rarely implemented.’ – implying either can fail to be implemented); perhaps it is wrong, or I misread it. Maybe they meant some *later* implementations did not bother to provide `-z`, `-n`, or both.

Comment: That's probably correct for some implementations, but I'm guessing there was "a first one"... and then the question is what did that first one do?   (-z/-n, =/!=, or both)

Comment: Just checked: V7 Unix supports all three forms. However, it doesn’t use argument counting for syntax disambiguation.

Comment: I’ve also found this: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/ – might be useful.

Comment: Thanks; that page took me to info about the PWB shell, derived from 4th. ed. Unix, which had 'test', so this is a strong contender for 'first' -- see my answer.  But first still does not answer 'why', at which we can only guess.